# Could anyone help me check my gibbs sampling code?

Tags: r, markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am now trying to write a Gibbs Sampling code based on the posteriors from a paper "Bayesian Regularization via Graph Laplacian", writer: Fei Liu, et.
When I run the code, it always show the error:

```
Error in eta_ii[i] = rinvgauss(n = 1, mean = mu_eta_ii, shape = a^2) : 
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Does anyone know why? Or does anyone do this paper's gibbs sampling before?
Thank you very much!

Here is my code:

```
 library(pscl)
  library(MASS)
  library(statmod)
p=ncol(x)
n=nrow(x)
In=diag(1,nrow=n,ncol=n)

#STEP1. generate variance from the posterior distribution
      #p(var|lamda,D)~Inverse Gamma(n/2,y'(In-X(X'X+rlamda)^-1X')y/2)
variance=function(lamda,X,Y){ 
var=rigamma(n,n/2,t(Y)%*%(In-X%*%solve(t(X)%*%X+r*lamda)%*%t(X))%*%Y/2)
mvar=mean(var)
return(mvar)
}

#STEP2. generate beta from the multivariate normal distribution
 #here I am not very sure about the meanninng of y_tuter
beta=function(var,lamda,X,Y){
mu_beta=solve(t(X)%*%X+r*lamda)%*%t(X)%*%Y
sg_beta=var*solve(t(X)%*%X+r*lamda)
beta=mvrnorm(n=n,mu_beta,sg_beta)
mbeta=colMeans(beta)
return(mbeta)
}

#STEP3. generate the sign of the lamda:c, based on the binomial dist
 signC=function(beta,var,X,Y){
   P=matrix(1,ncol=p,nrow=p)
   C=matrix(1,ncol=p,nrow=p)
   for (i in 1:p){
     for(j in 1:i){
       P[i,j]=1/(1+exp(-r*b*(abs(beta[i]-beta[j]-abs(beta[i]+beta[j]))/2*var))
       C[i,j]=rbinom(1, 1, P[i,j])
       if (C[i,j]==0){
         C[i,j]=-1
       }
       C[j,i]=C[i,j]
       if(i==j){
         C[i,i]=1
       }
     }
   }
   return(C)

 }

  #STEP4. generate the eta which is from the product of independent inverse

  Gaussian dists
 #1. for the eta_ii   
 eta_ii=function(var,beta){
 mu_eta_ii<-c()
 for(i in 1:p){
  mu_eta_ii=a*var*(abs(r^0.5*beta[i]))^(-1)
  eta_ii[i]=rinvgauss(n=1,mean= mu_eta_ii, shape=a^2)
  }
 return(eta_ii)
 }

#2. for the eta_ij
 eta_ij=function(C,var,beta){
   eta_ij=matrix(1,ncol=p,nrow=p)
   for(i in 1:p){
     for(j in 1:i){
       mu_eta_ij=b*var*(abs(r^0.5*(beta[i]+C[i,j]*beta[j])))^(-1)
       eta_ij[i,j]=rinvgauss(n=1,mean= mu_eta_ij, shape=b^2)
       eta_ij[j,i]=eta_ij[i,j]
       if (i==j){
         eta_ij[i,j]=1
       }
     }
   }
  return(eta_ij)
 }


  #STEP5. get the new lamda
 new_lamda=function(C,eta_ii,eta_ij){
   lamda=matrix(1,ncol=p,nrow=p)
   for (i in 1:p){
     for (j in 1:i){
       lamda[i,j]=C[i,j]*eta_ij[i,j]
       lamda[j,i]=lamda[i,j]
       if(i==j){
         lamda[i,j]=eta_ii[i]
       }
     }
   }
   return(lamda)
 }


 #After generate new parameters, we can replace the hyperparameters:r,a,b
 #set the value for gz,hr,gb
 ga=0.01
 hr=0.01
 gb=0.01

 #get the new r:GAMMA dist
 hyper_r=function(a,b,C,beta,var){
  shape=p/2+hr
  rate_p3=matrix(0,nrow=p*(p-1)/2,ncol=1)
  for (j in 1:p){
   for (i in 1:j){
      if(i<j){
          rate_p3[j-1]=(b/(2*var^0.5))*abs(beta[i]+C[i,j]*beta[j])
             }

                  }
               }

     rate=sum(beta*beta)/(2*var)+a*sum(abs(beta))/(2*var^0.5)+sum(rate_p3)

     r=rgamma(1,shape=shape,rate=rate)
      return(r)
       }


       #get the new a:exponential
       hyper_a=function(r,beta,var){
       rate=r*sum(abs(beta))/(2*var^0.5)
      a=rexp(1,rate=ga+rate)
       return(a)
        }


     #get the new b:exponential
     hyper_b=function(r,beta,var,C){
    rate_p2=matrix(0,nrow=p*(p-1)/2,ncol=1)
    for (j in 1:p){
      for (i in 1:j){
       if(i<j){
        rate_p2[j-1]=(r/(2*var^0.5))*abs(beta[i]+C[i,j]*beta[j])
        }

        }
      }
     b=rexp(1,rate=gb+rate_p2)
     return(b)
      }



       #start the Gibbs Sampler
      ga=0.01
      hr=0.01
     gb=0.01

       r=1
       a=1
       b=1
   sigma=diag(1,nrow=8,ncol=8)
    for (i in 1:8){
        for (j in 1:8){
          sigma[i,j]=0.7^abs(i-j)
                     }
                   }
      x<-mvrnorm(n=20, rep(0, 8),sigma)
      error<-rnorm(20,mean=0,sd=3)
      y<-3*x[1]+2*x[2]+1.5*x[3]+error

    lamda<-solve(cor(x))

    p=ncol(x)
    n=nrow(x)
     In=diag(1,nrow=n,ncol=n)

     VAR<-c()
       BETA<-matrix(0,ncol=p,nrow=2)

    burnIn=20
    for (m in 1:2){

  var<-variance(lamda,x,y)
  VAR[m]<-var
  beta<-beta(var,lamda,x,y)
  BETA[m,]<-beta
  C<-signC(beta,var,x,y)
  eta_ii<-eta_ii(var,beta)
  eta_ij<-eta_ij(C,var,beta)
  lamda<-new_lamda(C,eta_ii,eta_ij)
  r<-hyper_r(a,b,C,beta,var)
  a<-hyper_a(r,beta,var)
  b<-hyper_b(r,beta,var,C)

}
```

Comment: This is off topic here. It belongs on [codereview.SE].

Comment: @gung Code Review requires code that works (as far as the asker knows), so this does not belong there, either.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `eta_ii`, you attempt to use the value `eta_ii` as a vector by using the bracket notation to assign values to its entries.  Essentially you do this:

```
f <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:x) {
    f[i] <- i
  }
  return(f)
}
```

If I call this function, I get the same problem:

```
> f(2)
Error in f[i] <- i : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Breaking down this error message:

`object of type 'closure'`: "closure" is a synonym for "function" in R error messages.  So this is referring to `f`.

`is not subsettable`: Subsetting is what you are doing when you use a `[`.

So altogether this is saying `I don't know how to use a [ on f.  Are you sure that's what you want?`.  It's probably not what you want.

Reusing variable names in the way your code does is **a very bad practice**.  R is quite permissive in this aspect, but it probably shouldn't be, because the practice is confusing and unpredictable.  I would take some time to think hard about what you are naming things, you will thank yourself for doing so in the future.  You also have many issues with indentation and formatting, though that may be an artifact of copying and pasting.  Again, I would advise care and caution with your code formatting, it will help you immensely when you enter debugging mode.